# Can't log in after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login

*** Updates ***

2021-04-21 I installed the upgrades and everything seems to be working perfectly with 20.04LTS. Cursors are as they should be and windows I open are staying open. Thanks to everyone who made suggestions! I'm sure I will have more question in the future!

2021-04-20 I can now log on using cntl-alt-f3. There is a message that there are 58 updates that can be installed immediately and 7 are security updates. I listed them and saw one referring to desktop. Should I go ahead and install the updates?

Thanks again!

*** End Update ***

Here's yet another log in problem after upgrade to 20.04 question.

When I tried logging in via the GUI, I didn't get any sort of error message. The screen went dark and the login screen came back up. (I did click the icon to see what I entered and know that the password was typed correctly.)

I've looked at the similar questions and have tried cntl-alt-f3 and it tells me the password is incorrect. Even though I couldn't see what I had typed, I did it very carefully and believe I typed the correct password.

I believe if I hadn't powered off overnight, I wouldn't know about this problem. I did several restarts after the upgrade and everything worked perfectly.

So, after the log in failures, I booted up using a USB stick copy of 20.04 that I had been using on my old Win XP laptop to see if I wanted to go to Ubuntu. Works just fine but this is not a good long-term solution. I copied all of my files from the user home directory to an external hard drive and am thinking that the simplest solution would be to just install 20.04 from the USB stick. BUT, I would rather fix the log in problem than have to reinstall software that was running under 18.04 and rebuild from scratch..

Also, there were some error messages when I powered off that flew by too fast for me to read completely but I saw something about "could not unmount oldroot..." And, when I booted from USB and let it check the file system, it told me there were 3 files with errors. (Didn't say what the 3 files were and I wonder if the power off messages that went by so fast named the files.)

So, several questions:

Is there any way to trap the messages or find a log file with the power off error messages?

I believe that the upgrade gave me GNOME 2.8 (or 9 - not sure), but the USB version says it has GNOME 3 - why would a recent update have a lower version number than an image copy that I made over a year ago?

And, the question that started this, is it possible to fix my login and just continue with what I've got?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think the first thing we need to know is what hardware you are running? Do you know if the hardware is fully supported? and have you had any issues in the past on previous distrobutions such as 18.04 etc?

Comment: The login screen will clearly tell you if you have entererd an incorrrect username or password. "*The screen went dark and the login screen came back up.*" suggests a desktop crash instead of a wrong password. At GRUB, enter Recovery Mode. If you have a bad password, it will be recorded in /var/log/auth.log. If you have a desktop crash, it will be recorded in /var/crash. Additional information about boot/shutdown failures will be in /var/log/syslog. Your first task is to isolate specific error messages. Once you have clear error messages, then we can look at solutions.

Comment: You may want to check the *Xauthority* file by booting into the `single mode` to see if it is normal. It is a environmental variable *$XAUTHORITY* which in my case stored in */run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority* with `file privilege` *700*.

Comment: @DylanCoulbeck There were no issues running 18.04LTS. Lenovo ThinkPad T14 Gen 1 / Processor version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz / CPU INFO: UDI: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz - INTEL, Model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz, Number of cores: 4 - enabled, Number of threads: 8
Max speed: 2.100 GHz, Current speed: 2.112 GHz
Features: MMX, EM64T, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, AES, AVX, CLMUL, FMA, PSE, PSE-36, IDA/Turbo boost, HTT, XD, VMX
Cache L1: 4 x 32 KB Data, 4 x 32 KB Instruction
Cache L2: 4 x 256 KB Unified
Cache L3: 1 x 6 MB Unified

Comment: I see, regarding those specs you should not have any issues, I'd suggest if none of the provided fixes work provided this comment section and continue to have issues it's probably best to stick with 18.04.

Later releases need more time till it's stable, thats the only advice I can give at this stage :)

to add I didnt read the question properly so apologies for the unecessary question, tho the spec sheet is helpful :)

Comment: @DylanCoulbeck Thanks for your assurances on my hardware. This morning I let all the suggested modules upgrade and 20.04LTS appears to be working well. BUT, in case, there are problems down the road, how would I roll back to 18.04?